# how generate a document with repeated objects

Tags: json

guys I have this code which is written in `Json` as it is supposed to generate a document with repeated objects `_id` and `items`

I have used repeat function and passed a list to it with these objects , also i do not have clear understanding about what `objectid` do

```
'repeat(21, 0)': [ {_id :objectId()} 
                ,  items : items()} ]
```

but it is giving me this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

I am using this site `https://next.json-generator.com`

Comment: If you are encountering an error you should be posting your code, otherwise how can we able to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved guys , you can find the code below

```
[
  {
    'repeat(21, 0)': {
      _id: '{{objectId()}}',
      items: '{{company().toUpperCase()}}',
    }
  }
]
```

it is a list with an object which contain a function repeating its containing objects
, please correct me if i am wrong or give more clarification.